# c pointer array argument

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function(in some library) whose signature is this:

```
extern LIB3DSAPI void lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals(Lib3dsMesh *mesh, float (*face_normals)[3]);
```

what does it expect in second argument?

I tried this:

```
        float   *norm_verts[3];
        norm_verts=(float(*)[3])malloc(3*sizeof(float[3])*mesh->nfaces);
        lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals(mesh, norm_faces);
```

on the second line, it says `Expression must be modifiable value` and the third line says `argument of type float** is incompatible with parameter of type float(*)[3]`

My intuition was that `float* [3]` is just 3 pointers but why the hell is the `*` wrapped in brackets?

Comment: Hint: in Linux there are nifty cdecl and uncdecl tools for encoding and decoding cryptic C definitions to plain english.

Comment: I was just wondering, if this function computes the normals of the mesh, wouldn't you need an array with the same size as the number of faces in the mesh ?

Comment: @mux:ok, Yeah sorry, `lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals` calculates normals per face which would need an array of same size and there's another function to calculate per vertex normals which takes an array thrice as big. So I messed up while copying the code..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is wrapped in brackets to give it tighter binding. The 2nd arg to `lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals` is read "face_normals is a pointer to an array of 3 float`.

Try:

```
float   (*norm_verts)[3];
norm_verts=(float(*)[3])malloc(sizeof(*norm_verts)*mesh->nfaces);
lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals(mesh, norm_vets);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float (*face_normals)[3] // face_normals is a pointer (to an array of 3 floats)
float *norm_verts[3];    // norm_verts is an array of 3 pointers (to float)
```

Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers.
I suggest you read [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), starting with section 6.

Answer (score 1):

> My intuition was that `float* [3]` is just 3 pointers

It is.

It's also not what the code says.

The function is asking for a pointer to an array of three floats. The parentheses make sure that it is parsed that way by "binding" the `*` to the name and not the type.

```
Lib3dsMesh *mesh    = getMeshFromSomewhere();
float norm_faces[3] = {};

lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals(mesh, &norm_faces);
```

In this manner, the function `lib3ds_mesh_calculate_face_normals` knows that it is dealing with the original, actual array `norm_faces` and not some copy and not some name decayed to a pointer without dimension information.

This is *the* way to do "out" arguments with arrays without having to pass a `float*` and a separate length argument.